# How to submit a Form in Laravel?

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm working on this simple form and trying to submit it. Basically I created an array of users in my HomeController.php which then renders its data in the home.blade.php file (That part works fine). However when I try to submit the form I get an error that says: **Undefined variable: usersArray** .Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please? thank you so much in advance.

**Here's my Home.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(array('id' => 'activateForm')) !!}

{!! csrf_field() !!}

<div>

<!---Error messages inside of box-->
<div style="padding-left: 135px; width:815px;">

@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul class = "login-error-messages" style = "list-style-type:disc;">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
   </div>
   @endif
  </div>

  <div class="home-rounded-border  center-content">
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "checkAll" />Select All<span style="padding-left: 310px;font-weight: bold;">Email</span><br/>
    @foreach($usersArray as $key => $value)
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxUser{{$key}}" name="user-name-checkbox{{$key}} ">{{$value}}
            <input type = "email" class="styled-text  rounded" name = "name" id = "customer-name-inputField{{$key}}" placeholder=""/><br/><br/>
        </li>
    </ul>
    @endforeach

<center><input type = "submit" class="sign-in-button"value = "Submit"/></center>

   </br>
   <div id="statusMsg" style="margin: 0px 40px 0px 40px; background-color: #ffffff;"></div>

   <ul><li class="logout"><a href="logout"><span>Logout</span></a></li></ul>

  </div>

  <br/><br/>
  </div>
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's `return view('home', ['userId' => $adminId]);` on your `activateCustomer`. you are trying to render home view without `$usersArray`

Comment: Do I need to declare $userArray in activateCustomer? if yes how would the implementation be? Thanks!

Comment: if you want to show home view if the submission was sucessfull, you can call back to `home()` method using `return redirect()->to('home')`